# SQL Server 2014 Standard 2014 no access and bad preformance

Tags: sql, sql-server, performance, logging

My company looks after a server which is running SQL Server 2014 Standard Edition. The main application database on the server is replicated out to about 20 subscribers. The server has only been in operation for about a week and at the time of setting it up we moved the existing database and replication across from the old server. At that time we also changed the recovery model from Simple to Full.

The performance of the server hasn't been particularly good so far, even though it has 24 logical processors and 32 GB of RAM. However it seems to be SQL Server that has been performing badly due to locks etc. according to the event logs.

This morning we couldn't access any tables in Management Studio and after a period of time we decided to try restarting the service. The service did not seem to stop properly and we were forced to restart the server. After restarting the server everything seemed fine until we tried to expand out the 'Databases' tab in Management Studio. It just says 'expanding...' in the UI and after several minutes brings up a timeout error message. After clicking ok on this message we can browse all the system databases as normal but the main application database is not shown.

One of the problems that has come to light is that the log file has grown extremely large (over 1 TB).

This is a major problem now as you can imagine, since we cannot connect to the database to shrink the log file and no applications can connect to the database Connecting to the database using 'sqlcmd' doesn't work either. We can't 'open' the database.

Look forward to hearing if anyone has come across this before and knows of a solution.

Comment: This seems a better candidate for DBA.stackexchange.com

Comment: Agreed, try dba.stackexchange.com -- but also check your application event logs, the db might be recovering if it wasn't shut down cleanly -- and a 1TB log might take a very long time to recover.  Once you finally have it up and running, you can keep your log size in check with regularly scheduled backups (full/diff/log).  The log can't "shrink" until the database is backed up, and older log entries are marked for deletion.  Good luck.

Comment: "At that time we also changed the recovery model from Simple to Full." At that time, did you also set up log backups? If not, your log has been growing unchecked since you changed the recovery model.

Comment: Check the SQL Server error logs. I might show you if SQL Server is still trying to bring a database online or why it failed.

Comment: Got this sorted, had to wait a few hours for the database to recover and then shrank the log file.